# How can I use BruteForce Matching in openCV 3.2.0?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.2

I'm using opencv 3.2.0 and I'm trying to feature detecting, descriptor computing, and descriptor matching with FAST, BRISK, BruteForce, respectively. I'm using C++ with Visual studio 2017.

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
m_image_A = imread("a.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
m_image_B = imread("b.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> a = cv::FastFeatureDetector::create();
a->detect(m_image_A, keypoints1);
a->detect(m_image_B, keypoints2);
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> ex = cv::BRISK::create();
ex->compute(m_image_A, keypoints1, descriptors1);
ex->compute(m_image_B, keypoints2, descriptors2);

cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher;
std::vector<vector<DMatch>> matches;

matcher = cv::BFMatcher::create();
matcher->knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 2);
```

Here's my simple code for this and it doesn't operates properly.
I read many codes and tips, but I cannot find proper solution for my problem.

Is there anyone who can help me? How can I make it operate properly?

Comment: I edited the tags of this question to remove unnecessary ones and changed `opencv3.2` to `opencv`, as most people won't be looking in the specific release tags. This should help you get more responses. However, you should check the OpenCV tutorials; they have some which use the `BFMatcher`. For e.g., https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_description/feature_description.html. When you say "it doesn't operate properly" what do you mean? Be more specific with the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this method does'nt work, use the flann based method following by the homography method. It will give you the exact result of the distance between the keypoints and also how much points really matches at any sort of angle.

Answer (score 0):

BFMatcher constructor has the argument normType.

```
BFMatcher::create(NORM_HAMMING, false);
```

For SIFT and SURF the standard L1 norm can be applied but the documentation says for BRISK NORM_HAMMING should be used (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/da1/classcv_1_1BFMatcher.html) . Perhaps this solves the problem. But clearly you have to state what it means that your solution "does not operate properly".
Another problem I ran into when trying different combinations of descriptors and matching techniques was that some descriptors are saved in binary format and thus cannot be postprocessed easily with the standard matching methods.